# Tomcat Couldn't get lock for log file

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ioexception

I have a Vaadin project and I have some resource to manage in some folders. I have, for example, a custom logger and I want to save that log in WebContent/WEB-INF folder, but when I create the file handler I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for pathtofile
```

This is how I create that FileHandler:

```
String baseDir = getContext().getBaseDirectory().getPath();
String path = URLDecoder.decode(baseDir + File.separator + "WEB-INF"+ File.separator + logsPath + File.separator + logName, "UTF-8");
handler = new FileHandler(path, true);
```

Where logsPath is a property loaded correctly. When I inspect from debug the path string is ok.
I launch the application from Eclipse. 
I noticed that the tmp0 folder created by eclipse for running the application are readonly, is it right?
Why I get that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: I created a "logs" folder under WebContent folder and I put an empty file in it, because Tomcat does not deploy empty folders.